# Why does my Google Colab Session run out of ram?

Tags: python, opencv, out-of-memory, google-colaboratory

I have several images in a folder and i am trying to turn each one into grayscale and save them into another folder

Google Colab session keeps crashing due to running out of ram and i have tried using del on every variable

here is my code

```
img_array = []

for filename in FileArray:
    img = cv2.imread('train/train/Img-'+filename)
    height, width, layers = img.shape
    size = (width, height)
    img_array.append(img)

    image = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    cv2.imwrite('train/gray/Img-'+filename, image)
    del img
    del height
    del width
    del layers
    del size
    del image
```

Comment: What is your question, exactly? Have you done any profiling?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even though you are deleting `img`, the image is still held in memory in the `img_array` list.  If you have a lot of images in `FileArray`, you can very quickly chew through your RAM by keep them all in memory.

Try removing the line:

```
img_array.append(img)
```

Comment: My assumption was that they needed to add all the images to `img_array` because they’re being used for something elsewhere, I’m curious to find out if that’s really the case.

Comment: @AMC yes it's a deep learning project where this img_array will be fed to a DCGAN

Comment: @James Thank You that fixed it for me I will try to store them in a different way to avoid this problem

Comment: No problem.  Please remember to mark the question as answered by clicking the little check mark next to the answer.

Comment: Hi, I'm facing the same issue where I read 4352 images of `(512*512*3)` on a Colab pro after converting the list to an Np Array. How did you solve it? Removing the append won't work for me, cuz I need them stored for the training.

Comment: You should use a smaller batch size than 4352 and load in the images for each batch.  Or better still load in enough images for several batches and as the current images are popped from the array and processed, concurrently open an other batch and append.

Comment: @James so what your saying is to create the batches manually? If that the case, how to feed the model training in this way?

Comment: I solved it by using batches and using a maxium of 8 images per batch @asendjasni